# NSOperation and running a class with method

Tags: cocoa, nsoperation

Let's say I have a class and *classMain is an object for this class. Now this class as a instance method - `performAction`. So normally to run the method, I would do:

```
[classMain performAction]
```

Now if i want to use `NSOperationQueue` to run this, I would do:

```
NSOperationqueue *opQueue = [[NSOperation alloc] init];
[opQueue addOperation: classMain].
```

What i want to do is actually add `[classMain performAction]` to the queue, so I can run the method I want ?

Also is there a better recommend way of running threads ( so my application does not get locked) in 10.7 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to run threads and to run various actions on different threads.  You may find this resource helpful:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html

And if you just have a simple task that you want to run in the background without locking your app, you may find that the most straightforward solution is to use [performSelectorInBackground:withObject:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorInBackground%3awithObject%3a).

As for which approach is recommended, it really depends upon your specific use-case and what sort of work you are offloading to a separate thread.

Comment: One issue with using performSelectorInBackground:withObject: though. It returns to void. So how would I be able to get a return value when I use this ?